# Android sip calling

Tags: android, sip, voip, nativeapplication, sip-stack

we want to use conference calling in our app we managed to make a call but we are not able to make a conference call . 
we tried to sipcoudiocall.attachCall(sipSession,sessionDescription);
but we are not able to make conference call can you help.

Comment: Show what have you tried along with code and tell about your problem/error as well